# It is possible to make different attributes on each element?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Need Help, please!

My code is this done fast:

```
[XmlRoot("monster")]
public class monster
{
    public List<flag> flags { get; set; }
}

public class flag
{
    [XmlAttribute("summonable")]
    public int summonable { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("attackable")]
    public int attackable { get; set; }
}

 public void XML()
 { monster monster = new monster
            {
                flags = new List<flag>
                {
                    new flag() { summonable = 0 },
                    new flag() { attackable = 0 }
                }
            };
 }
```

He is coming out well , and I'm using List<> :

```
<monster>
 <flags>
  <flag summonable="0" attackable="0" />
  <flag summonable="0" attackable="0" />
</flags>
</monster>
```

I need like this:

```
<monster>
<flags>
    <flag summonable="0"/>
    <flag attackable="0"/>
</flags>
</monster>
```

Thank everyone who helped me ... Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Is the set of flag values fixed (i.e. only `summonable` and `attackable`) or could there by any number of flags?

Comment: only summonable and attackable

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you make them your own elements? E.g, <summonable /> and <attackable />?

Comment: Because I'm serializing a file for a game ready. And the Game only accepts so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since your set of flags is fixed, I would not recommend a `List<flag>` inside your `monster` class.  Instead I would have a single `flag` object, like so:

```
[XmlRoot("monster")]
public class monster
{
    public flags flags { get; set; }
}

public class flags
{
    public int summonable { get; set; }

    public int attackable { get; set; }

    // Add more as required.
}
```

Now, to serialize this to XML as required, you can introduce a `public Flag[] Flags` property that you populate with the names and values of your fixed attributes.  That in turn can have an [`[XmlAnyAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute.aspx) attribute array that you populate with the attribute name and value, like so:

```
[XmlRoot("monster")]
public class monster
{
    public flags flags { get; set; }
}

public class flags
{
    const string SummonableName = "summonable"; // In c# 6.0 use nameof(summonable)
    const string AttackableName = "attackable"; // See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int summonable { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int attackable { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("flag")]
    public Flag[] Flags
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new Flag { Name = SummonableName, Value = XmlConvert.ToString(summonable) },
                new Flag { Name = AttackableName, Value = XmlConvert.ToString(attackable) },
            };
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            foreach (var attr in value)
            {
                if (attr.Name == SummonableName)
                    summonable = XmlConvert.ToInt32(attr.Value);
                else if (attr.Name == AttackableName)
                    attackable = XmlConvert.ToInt32(attr.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Flag
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] XmlAttributes
    {
        get
        {
            var attr = new XmlDocument().CreateAttribute(Name.ToString());
            attr.Value = Value;
            return new [] { attr };
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
            {
                Name = null;
                Value = null;
            }
            else if (value.Length == 1)
            {
                Name = value[0].Name;
                Value = value[0].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Too many attributes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the XML will look like:

```
<monster>
  <flags>
    <flag summonable="0" />
    <flag attackable="0" />
  </flags>
</monster>
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CHqU72).

Comment: @GustavoBatista - I can't think of one right away.  If your `flag` class had lots of properties it might be more compact to use reflection.  What you're doing sort of goes against the design of `XmlSerializer` which is designed to map XML to elements and attributes using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do what you need by marking `flag` class with `abstract` and deriving it in two classes in the following way:

```
public abstract class flag
{

}

public class summonableFlag : flag
{
    [XmlAttribute("summonable")]
    public int summonable { get; set; }
}

public class attackableFlag : flag
{
    [XmlAttribute("attackable")]
    public int attackable { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to mark `List<flag>` with `XmlElementAttribute` to serialize your items as `flag`:

```
[XmlRoot("monster")]
public class monster
{
    [XmlElement(elementName: "flag")]
    public List<flag> flags { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, creation of your `monster` object will look as follows:

```
 monster monster = new monster
            {
                flags = new List<flag>
                {
                    new summonableFlag() { summonable = 0 },
                    new attackableFlag() { attackable = 0 }
                }
            };
```

After this I believe that you will get the required result. I have not tested it, so write if you will have problems with this solution.

Comment: Hello, it worked, but how do I take out the namespace?                                                                                                   <flag **d3p1:type="summonableFlag"** summonable="0" **xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** />

Comment: @GustavoBatista, that is a separate question and requires us to know how you're generating the XML.

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing attribute names with attribute values. I believe what can help you is this:

```
[XmlRoot("monster")]
public class monster
{
    public List<flag> flags { get; set; }
}

public class flag
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

}



public void XML() { 
    monster monster = new monster
    {
            flags = new List<flag>
            {
                new flag() { Name="summonable", Value = 0 },
                new flag() { Name="attackable", Value =0 }
            }
        };
     }
```

Which should yield what you need

```
<monster>
 <flags>
  <flag Name="Summonable" Value="0" />
  <flag Name="Attackable" Value="0" />
</flags>
</monster>
```

Comment: I don't want to Name and Value

Comment: That's unfortunate I could not help you more. The other two answers on here are quite good, but be wary of maintainability.

Comment: Thank You Very Much